# Could the friction between gas be used to cause an electric discharge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, friction, air, plasma-physics

For example, Let's say I connect two air cannons to a tube so that they're facing each other with the tube in the middle. When I press a button, the cannons will fire, shooting air in opposite directions. If I shot the air with enough energy and pressure, could I get an electric discharge?

If yes, could this discharge be used to turn one of the gases into a plasma?

Answer (score 1):

By *electric discharge* I assume you mean something like lightning. If so it's hard to see how your colliding pressure waves could generate any charge separation so there won't be any discharges.

If the amount of energy in the pressure waves is really, really big then the collision will cause enough heating to ionise the gases and create a plasma. However you are talking about absurd amounts of energy - far beyond what you could achieve from an air cannon.

Comment: In clouds, movement of air generates separation of charge and causes lightning. What is different there?

Comment: Clouds contain ice crystals and it's the interactions between the air and the ice crystals that generate the charge separation.